# Одно значение true на группу записей в таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не получается придумать как сделать проверку на уровне БД.
СУБД PostgreSQL.

Задача.   Есть записи в таблице типы уведомлений.
Есть таблица типов

```
CREATE TABLE Types(
-- Таблица типов уведомлений.
id serial UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- номер типа уведомления.
title varchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- Название типа уведомления.
description varchar(255) -- описание типа опционально.

);

CREATE TABLE Templates(
-- Общая таблица шаблонов.
id serial  UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- уникальный идентификатор шаблона.
type varchar(100) REFERENCES Types(id), -- внешний ключ на тип уведомления.
subject varchar(77), -- заголовок письма
html_body text, -- тело письма в формате html
text_body text, -- тело письма в формате плоского тектса
version varchar(255), -- версия шаблона возможно текстовое описание
created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(), -- время создания шаблона
in_use boolean DEFAULT FALSE, -- означет что шаблон в использовании
-- шаблоны в пределах одного типа должны иметь уникальный идетификатор в виде  версии.
CONSTRAINT unique_template_type_version UNIQUE (type, version),
);
```

Подскажите как добиться эффекта чтобы в таблице Templates в поле in_use только у одной записи конкретного типа стояло значение true?
Логика такая, что версий шаблонов определенного типа может быть много а использоваться в конкретный момент должен только один.
Чтобы запрос
`SELECT * FROM Templates WHERE type=some_type_id and in_use=True;`
гарантированно возвращал одну запись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете создать уникальный частичный индекс:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON templates (type) WHERE in_use;
```

Comment: А с какой целью сам in_use в индекс включаете? Ради IOS вряд ли, тогда чтобы просто увеличить размер индекса?

Comment: @Мелкий Ошибся немного. Исправил. Спасибо.

Comment: немного не пойму логику(механизм) работы.  у меня все остальный записи будут с значением False?

Comment: @Vetos Этот индекс проверяет, что запись с таким `type` и `in_use = true` будет только одна. На записи с `in_use = false` этот индекс внимания не обращает, их может быть сколько угодно. Если это не то, что вам нужно, уточните вопрос.

Comment: @Ainar-G, похоже это то что нужно я сейчас проверяю

Comment: @Ainar-G, да это то что нужно. спасибо.